# Uploading and displaying image - ReactJs, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

App is running on Node.js and React. In database (mongodb used) I have collection Rooms that contains details about particular room.

I have an option to add new room and there is an option to upload image for that particular room.

Here is code for room model.

***SERVER PART***

**UserModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define our model
const roomSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number },
    room_type: { type: String },
    nb_guests: { type: Number },
    imageData: {type: String}
});

// Create the model class
const ModelClass = mongoose.model('room', roomSchema);

// Export the model
module.exports = ModelClass;
```

This is add route:

**room.route.js**

```
// Defined store route
roomRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
    let room = new Room(req.body);
    room.save()
      .then(room => {
        res.status(200).json({'room': 'room is added successfully'});
      })
      .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
      });
  });
```

And here is form where I add new room:

**CreateRoom.js**

```
export default class CreateRoom extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangePrice = this.onChangePrice.bind(this);
        this.onChangeGuests = this.onChangeGuests.bind(this);
        this.onChangeRoomType = this.onChangeRoomType.bind(this);
        this.onImageUpload = this.onImageUpload.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            price: '',
            room_type: '',
            nb_guests: '',
            imageData: ''
        }
    }

    onChangeTitle(e) {
        console.log('title changed');
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeDescription(e) {
        console.log('description changed');
        this.setState({
            description: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePrice(e) {
        console.log('price changed');
        this.setState({
            price: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeGuests(e) {
        console.log('guests changed');
        this.setState({
            nb_guests: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeRoomType(e) {
        console.log('room changed');
        this.setState({
            room_type: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onImageUpload = event => {
        console.log('picture updated');
        this.setState({
            imageData: event.target.files[0]
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(`Form submitted:`);

        const newRoom = {
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            price: this.state.price,
            nb_guests: this.state.nb_guests,
            room_type: this.state.room_type,
            imageData: this.state.imageData
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:3090/admin/add', newRoom)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.setState({
            title: '',
            description: '',
            price: '',
            room_type: '',
            nb_guests: '',
            imageData: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
                        <div className="container">
                            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-bold">Create new room</h1>
                            <p>Provide all needed details</p>
                            <div className="row"></div>
                            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="title" className="col-form-label">Title:</label>
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        value={this.state.title}
                                        onChange={this.onChangeTitle}
                                        className="form-control" id="title" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="message-text" className="col-form-label">Description:</label>
                                    <textarea
                                        type="text"
                                        value={this.state.description}
                                        onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                                        className="form-control" id="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="title" className="col-form-label">Price:</label>
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        value={this.state.price}
                                        onChange={this.onChangePrice}
                                        className="form-control" id="price" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlSelect1">Number of guests:</label>
                                    <select onChange={this.onChangeGuests} className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlSelect1">Room type:</label>
                                    <select onChange={this.onChangeRoomType} className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                        <option>Single</option>
                                        <option>Double</option>
                                        <option>Apartment</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload photo</label>
                                    <input type="file" onChange={this.imageUpload} class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" />
                                </div>

                                <br />
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Create room" className="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>

                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

After clicking on Create Room button data is added to database and "something" is added to imageData field in room collection but I think not correctly.

I am trying to display it on LandingPage like this:

**LandingPage.js**

```
const Room = props => (

    <div className = "col-md-4" >
        <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <img src={props.room.imageData} class="card-img-top" alt="..." width="100%" height="225" />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{props.room.title}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">{props.room.description}</p>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div className="btn-group">
                    <Link  className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" to={"/view/"+props.room._id}>View</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div >
)

export default class LandingPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            rooms: [],
            term:''
        }
        this.onSearchHandler = this.onSearchHandler.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3090/admin/')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    rooms: response.data
                })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            })
    }

    roomList = () => {
        const { rooms, term } = this.state;

        if (!term) {
          return rooms.map(function(currentRoom, i) {
            return <Room room={currentRoom} key={i} />;
          });
        } else {
          return rooms
            .filter(room => {
              return room.nb_guests === term;
            })
            .map(matchingRoom => {
              return <Room room={matchingRoom} />;
            });
        }
      };

      onSearchHandler = e => {
        this.setState({
          term: parseFloat(e.target.value)
        });
      };

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <LPheader />
                <Carousel />
                <div>
                    <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <form>
                                    <input 
                                    type="text"
                                    onChange={this.onSearchHandler}
                                    value={this.state.term}
                                    />
                                </form>
                                {this.roomList()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Using this line of code I am trying to display it but it's not working:

```
<img src={props.room.imageData} class="card-img-top" alt="..." width="100%" height="225" />
```

I am not sure am I maybe uploading it wrong to database or am I displaying it wrong.

I have no error but image is just not being displayed.

Any tip is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you expected it is about the image not being handled correctly, what you saved to the database is the binary of the image represented as text (this might even cause corruption to the image) you need to handle saving the image yourself, and you have two options here:

1) You decide to save the image as a string, and then before saving the image you need to decode it to base64 to ensure that the database does not corrupt it's data, after that you display it directly in the image src, your image src should look something like this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {base64data==}"  />
```

2) You decide to save the image as file in your webserver, and you handle the link to the file to the image in the image src

I assume that there is some utility for your server out there that do one of the previous steps for you/ or do both depending on the image size. If you don't want to implement that yourself

Comment: My image src looks like this `<img src={props.room.imageData}/>`  do you think I should rewrite it like `<img src="data:image/png;base64, {base64data== props.room.imageData }"/>` or?

Comment: @user9347049 you could, but if you decide to go with this approach you will need to decode the image to base64 before saving to the database

Comment: I got completely lost :/